# How to use collection to merge arrays in laravel so that one becomes the key?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-collection

I have an array of arrays like so:

```
array (
array("Delhi", 22, "The capital of India"), 
array("Varanasi", 23, "Oldest Living City"), 
array ("Moscow", 24, "Capital of Russia"), 
array ("Konya", 25, "The city of Rumi"), 
array("Salzburg", 26, "The city of Mozart")
);
```

I want to make an associated collection like so:

```
['city' => "Delhi",
'id' => 22,
'description' => "The capital of India"
], 
['city' => "Varanasi",
'id' => 23,
'description' => "Oldest Living City"
], 
['city' => "Moscow",
'id' => 24,
'description' => "Captial of Russia"
]
```

This can be done by passing the data through a loop but is there anything in the collection that can get this done?

Comment: Related: [Replace indexed keys in each row of a 2d array with a static word followed by an incremented counter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27475496/2943403)

Comment: Native PHP duplicate question: [How to add keys to an existing multiple array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35234414/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use array_combine or combine from Laravel

```
$collection = array(
    array("Delhi", 22, "The capital of India"),
    array("Varanasi", 23, "Oldest Living City"),
    array("Moscow", 24, "Capital of Russia"),
    array("Konya", 25, "The city of Rumi"),
    array("Salzburg", 26, "The city of Mozart")
);


array_map(function($array){
    return array_combine(['city', 'id', 'description'], $array);
}, $collection);

//Or with a Laravel collection
collect($collection)->map(function($arr){
    return array_combine(['city', 'id', 'description'], $arr);
});
```

Comment: I have a small difficulty in understanding the logic here... I will explain how...

Here, `array_combine(['city', 'id', 'description'], $array);` will work only if $array is one of the rows of our collection eg:     `array("Salzburg", 26, "The city of Mozart")`

Also we have called array_map function which takes 2 inputs, the first one is the unnamed function while the 2nd one is the collection. 

How does this unnamed function take $array as the input?

Comment: That is just how array_map works (map being the Laravel equivalent)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php